# I run STIGs and I would like to be able to run a set of commands for those about:config entries to get a return on the settings

Tags: powershell, firefox

What PowerShell commands are used to pull the Firefox settings, particularly the about:config settings.

Comment: There is no ready made PowerShell cmdlet to do this. You have to identify it, if the settings are stored in disk in readable format, you can read it using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in 1-3 files on the local drive. See the [firefox article.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/965842)